# rails pass variable to model from controller not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model, var

Im trying to pass a variable from controller to my form to no avail.

Its working in another controller but cannot make it work for new user registrations.

```
  def update
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    @profile.form = "signup"
    ...
  end
```

Inside model I can do `@profile.form` to get the value

This does not work for new user registrations:
inside create action:

```
 undefined method `form=' for nil:NilClass
```

how to pass a variable to my model upon new user registration? `User = User.new` then `@user.form == "signup"` does not work either, i have :form in my attributes accessible list

Part of model:

```
  attr_accessible form
  ...
  validates :city_id, :presence => true, :if => :signup?


  def signup?
    #@profile.form == "signup"
    #@user.form == "signup"
    if self.form == "signup"
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
```

EDIT 1:
Still unable to pass a param to the model :S:S:S tried every possible way and google found solution.

The create method for my registrations#create =

```
  def create
    profile = Profile.new
    profile.form = "signup"

    super
  end
```

Comment: you should also post here the relevant code in models

Comment: @LukasStejskal updated the question with more info on the models

Comment: Would you also provide the codes of the views ?

Comment: @user1022209 posted the create method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly your problem is .
What I understand after I read your problem statement twice is that you tried to "new" a instance of Profile, assign its form attribute. And use its instance method `signup?` to do validation. But you get an error after on `self.form`  because `self` reference to the `nil Class`

I think you should change `profile` to `@profile` inside the create method.
Just by guess after reading [ruby guide about instance variable](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/instancevars.html),
My thought is that declaring the instance variable that will be added dynamically inside the controller structure and later they are passed to the model. And it is always `@...` inside controller generated by `rails g scaffold`.

Just give it a try :)

Comment: def create { @profile = Profile.new; @profile.form =="signup" } then inside the model signup? method i do if @profile.form == "signup" return true and this fails with undefined method `form' for nil:NilClass arghh this is really really frustrating

Comment: Try to 。use self.form =="signup" in your method

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. I believe what you want to do is have a virtual attribute 'form' of an object a certain value. I.e. does form exist in the database as well. If it doesn't you should be using `attr_accessor :form`
[Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor)

This defines the getter and setter method for form in the class where it is being invoked.

However, the error you stated is something radically different.

> undefined method `form=' for nil:NilClass

This merely means a profile with the id being passed in the params does not exist. i.e. if we are updating params id = 222, a database record with id 222 does not exist for Profile.

Comment: in profilescontroller#update it works, there i set @profile.form = "signup" but on user registration there is only create action where this can be set, so im still in the dark on this

Comment: Please share your create method. I apologize if I was unclear earlier, however what I am trying to say is that the variable on which you are trying to do .form = is not a reference to a Profile object. It is `nil`

Comment: :Ive posted the create method hope that clears things up a bit